# Unable to connect to Azure Service Management API from Azure Websites

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to connect to Azure Service Management API (this is an WCF https call with a certificate attached).
Getting the "**Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'management.core.windows.net'.** With inner exception: **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**" error

I've tried the following settings suggested on the internet:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Certificate is attached as an object serialized via byte array. It is not in the certificate store, so, there are no permission issues in reading it from the certificate store.

Here is a relevant section from our web.config's system.serviceModel

```
<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WindowsAzureServiceManagement_WebHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxBytesPerRead="10000000" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://management.core.windows.net" 
                        binding="webHttpBinding" 
                        bindingConfiguration="WindowsAzureServiceManagement_WebHttpBinding" 
                        contract="AzureWatch.WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement.IServiceManagement" 
                        name="WindowsAzureEndPoint" />
  <endpoint address="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="Service.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
</client>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: From where are you getting your certificate byte array?

Comment: From external storage.  Retrieval of the byte array works fine.

Comment: Sorry, but I should have been more clearer in my earlier comment. What I meant to ask was whether you created this byte array from a "cer" file or a "pfx" file. I think the question is whether the byte array you're using to reconstruct the certificate has the certificate's private data in it or not? You can try using the data from a publish settings file as well.

Comment: Gaurav, this is a pfx certificate.  It works fine from on-premises during testing, it also works fine from a full-featured Azure WebRole.

Comment: Hmm...interesting. I'll also give it a try and get back.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I'm guessing this didn't work out for you? I'm facing the same issue.